# Download and change the extension of a file generated with JSP

Tags: jsp, csv, file-conversion

I am generating a csv (comma separated value) file with Java Server Pages (JSP). The URL shows "`my_generated_csv.jsp`".

What I want to do is simple: The user clicks "`Generate`" which downloads the generated `CSV` file. I'd like to generate it with the JSP. Do I need to rethink my approach?

#### Edit:

The following code works to make the file downloadable, but the extension remains the same. Does anyone know how to change it?

```
<% response.setContentType("text/csv"); %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
response.setContentType("application/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=myfile.csv");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have JSP save the file, and then give the user a link to the file. Either that or give the page the MIME type of a csv file (text/csv).

I believe you would use

```
<% response.setContentType("text/csv"); %>
```

To set the mime type.

Comment: It works to make the file downloadable, but the extension remains the same